# Should I add an "and" in this sentence? "They start to work with more translators (and) in more languages."

Tags: word-usage

I am thinking one sentence like this:

> They start to work with more translators (*and*) in more languages.

This means, they used to work with only one or two translator(s) in one or two languages before, but now they expanded their business to more markets.

Should I put that *and* here?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?  The use of the simple present tense is incorrect here for the context mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add the **and**:

> They *have started* to work with more translators **and** in more languages.

since the work they are doing is translating into **more** languages, not that they need more languages to work with the translators (presumably all the translators speak one common language with the **they**).

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* the "*and*" : either construction works, and the subtle difference in meaning is too subtle for me to currently put into words.  Perhaps so subtle that it doesn't actually exist.

> They started to work on more languages with more translators.

i.e. they did not simply expand the languages worked on, while using the same translators they always had.  They also added new translators.

It has the same meaning in both of the original poster's phrasing's and in the alternative shown here.